# What's the difference between 종류 and 유형?

Tags: vocabulary

They both translate to "kind, type, category". They share one Hanja (유/류). It seems that 종류 is used more with real objects and 유형 with abstract concepts. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

유형 is more like "**Shape**, **Characteristic**", while 종류 has emphasis on "**Sort**"

Let me show some examples.

> The protagonist of the drama is a typical type of father.

The example can be represented as "The protagonist of the drama has typical **characteristics** of father". Therefore, it is more appropriate to use 유형 in this case.

> There are various types of goods in department stores.

In this example, it is more related to **sort** (group) , not their characteristics. Of course, they are sorted(grouped) by some characteristics or criteria, but more emphasis on sorting itself. Therefore, 종류 is more appropriate.

> Types of mammals

Rabbit, elephant, lion, tiger, etc.. (a group) - 종류

> Types of people who are not helpful to your life

People who are selfish, People who are mean, People who always lie, etc.. (a characteristic) - 유형